# Multiplicar variables PHP y jquery mostrando resultado en un div

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo una tabla con el campo Precio que se extrae de mysqli por php, y otro campo Cantidad que es un select (valores del 0 al 10) que los extraigo con jquery, ocupar jquery para detectar el cambio de valor del select. 
¿Cómo muestro el resultado de la multiplicación de ambos valores en un div respuesta? Claro, sin recargar la página.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("select[name=ant01]").change(function(){
            alert($('select[name=ant01]').val());
        });
});
</script>
```

```html
<table class="table">
   <thead>
<tr>
 <th>Nombre/Descripción</th>
 <th>Cant</th>
 <th>Precio</th>
</tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
<tr>
 <td><b>Antojitos</b></td>
 <td>
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Cant:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="ant01">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
 </td>
 <td id="ant01_precio">
       <?php echo $variable_php_precio; ?>
    <div id="respuesta"></div>
 </td>
</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Buenas! no me queda del todo claro lo que buscas, vos tenes una tabla con n elementos? o es sólo un renglón con 2 valores que tenes que multiplicar?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar usar el evento ***Onchange***, esto hace que cada opción seleccionada de un elemento <.select> ejecute una función, esto hará que tu importe cambie cada vez que selecciones una cantidad diferente:

```
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Nombre/Descripción</th>
   <th>Cant</th>
   <th>Precio</th>
   <th>Importe</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td><b>Antojitos</b></td>
 <td>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Cant:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="ant01" onchange="Calcular()">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>
    </div>
 </td>
 <td id="ant01_precio">
    <?php echo $variable_php_precio; ?>
 </td>
 <td id="respuesta"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Luego con jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function Calcular () {
   cantidad = $('#ant01').val();  //Capturamos los valores por el id
   precio = $('#ant01_precio').text();
   importe = cantidad*precio;
   $('#respuesta').html(importe);
 }
</script>
```

Saludos

Comment: Estimado Aldair, el resultado importe, cómo lo guardo en una variable PHP para usarlo en la plantilla posteriormente?

Comment: Hola Mario, Podrías hacerlo mediante Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Podés probar con esta función de jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name=ant01]").change(function(){
        var precio = parseFloat($( "#ant01_precio" ).text()),
            cantidad = $('select[name=ant01]').val(),
            resultado = precio*cantidad;
            $( "#resultado" ).html(resultado);
        });
});
</script>
```

Lo que hace es cargar en la variable `precio` el texto de `#ant01_precio` y convertirlo a valor númerico a través de la función `parseFloat()`. Luego carga en la variable `cantidad` el valor del selector `select[name=ant01]` y finalmente las multiplica en la variable `resultado`. Luego lo inserta con la función `html()` en otro campo con id `#resultado`.

En la tabla tenés que dejar el campo de valor único y agregar uno donde se muestre el resultado:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre/Descripción</th>
            <th>Cant</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Antojitos</b></td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="sel1">Cant:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="ant01">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="ant01_precio">10.50</td>
            <td id="resultado"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```